# How to sort two lists that correspond?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have two lists:

```
names = [sam, tim, ben, jack, frank]
ages = [10, 22, 18, 17, 14]
```

What I'm trying to do is sort these by greatest to least and print them so that they are printed vertically. Output:

```
tim 22
ben 18
jack 17
frank 14
sam 10
```

This is what I have so far:

```
for age, name in zip(ages, names):
  print(age, name)
```

This prints out the two lists side by side together, however I'm not sure how to sort ages from greatest to least without messing up the relationship of the lists. Thanks in advance, I'm also new to coding so If you could explain your suggestion it would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
data = list(zip(names, ages))
data.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
for val in data:
    print(val[0], val[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code !

**Code :**

```
names = ['sam', 'tim', 'ben', 'jack', 'frank']
ages = [10, 22, 18, 17, 14]
for i in range(0,len(ages)):
    for j in range(i,len(ages)):
        temp_age = ages[i]
        ages[i]=ages[j]
        ages[j]=temp_age

        temp_name = names[i]
        names[i]=names[j]
        names[j]=temp_name

print(ages)
print(names)
```

**Output :**

```
[14, 17, 18, 22, 10]                                                                                                   
['frank', 'jack', 'ben', 'tim', 'sam']
```